# CCLabelBMFont Label takes long time to load!

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a game. In game there is a help text. The game menus are transitioned on sliding in and out manner. Like if you click "Help" button on "Main Menu", Main menu slides out and help menu slides in.

Now i got problem while loading "Help Menu". The help menu consists of a scroll view and help texts are loaded in scrollview when it is initialized. The Text in Help Menu are CCLabelBMFont Label. The help text has multiples lines (upto 146) lines. My problem is when I click on Help menu, the sliding In takes up to 10 secs to come up. I know it's due to the long help text that is created using CCLabelBMFont.

Is there any solution of this case. When I decrease the lines of help text to 50, it works fine. I directly created the label with following code in HelpMenuLayer.m

```
CCLabelBMFont *contentLabel = [[CCLabelBMFont alloc] initWithString:@"Objective:"
                "\n........."
                      .
              .
              .
                                                                fntFile:"fontFile.fnt"];
        contentLabel.position = ccp(0.0f, 0.0f);
                [scrollview addChild:contentLabel]
                [contentLabel release];
```

Any comments or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. I really need help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the above issue using png image. And wrote down in some steps in following blog of mine. Please visit following link.

http://learninprogram.blogspot.com/2011/06/solution-to-cclabelbmfont-bitmap-fonts.html

Thanks for everyone who tried to help me and helped me actually. Happy sharing!!

Answer (score 0):

Well it is probably UIKit causing any slowness.  Cocos2D and UIKit do not play well together in my experience.

Anyway I don't know for sure what is wrong.  Here is my usage of CCLabelBMFont (which does not use UIKit but it should be the same):

```
CCLabelBMFont *multiplierLabel = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [player scoreMultiplier]] fntFile:@"projectOneTitle1.fnt"];
multiplierLabel.position = ccp(winSize.width*0.9, winSize.height*0.95);
multiplierLabel.tag = 9845;
[self addChild:multiplierLabel];
```

That probably won't help, but in the off chance that it does I am posting it.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aaron. I changed my code as above, but it also doesn't seems helping me. :( Previously I used ALLabelAtlas for creating label and it worked fine. But after I upgraded my cocos2d to 0.99.5, the ALLabelAtlas didn't worked so i switched to CCLabelBMFont.

Comment: But it seems ALLabelAtas draw long labels faster than CCLabelBMFont. Any new ideas ? It would be bad to wait 8 to 10 sec to load a text label of line 100. :(

Comment: I'm not sure.  Maybe try using CCLabelTTF?  It isn't usually recommended because it is considered slow and expensive, but maybe it will work better with UIKit than CCLabelBMFont?  Can you explain the  "\n........." bit in your code snippet?  That confuses me.

Comment: If it takes me a little bit to answer don't worry I'll be back.  I'm just coding and I refresh when I remember to :)

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I guess I will try using CCLabelTTF. And post the result again. The "\n....." means that I have used multiline texts to display a single label. like

`@"objectives:"`
`"\nThese are objectives"`
`"\n1. Objective 1"`

and so on. Those are continuous text and "\n" is for new line. (next line). Anyway I am very grateful for your help. My deadline is done and I am just stuck over here :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure line breaks don't work in CCLabelBMFont.  I tried it once before and it actually printed out the \n.  I doubt that would make it draw slowly though.

Comment: The line breaks worked for me though :). But main problem is slow loading which was due to rendering of long label fonts. so... i used my above method which was easy and cool :) (faster one). Anyway thanks for your interest.